# Conditionally assign a table variable in a DAX query (within an SSRS dataset)

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, dax

I'm working on an SSRS dataset, trying to write a DAX query that can filter a table in a tabular model based on user input. The specific challenge is that I am trying to conditionally create a DAX table variable based on input from a user.

Simplified example:  Say I have a table in my tabular model called "Groups" with two columns "GroupID" and "GroupLabel".  Based on input from the user, I need to create a table variable (something akin to a SQL temp table) that contains the GroupID's from the "Groups" table that correspond with the user-input "GroupLabel".  I have successfully accomplished this via the following:

```
DEFINE
VAR GroupIDs_Selected = 
SUMMARIZE(
CALCULATETABLE(
'Groups', 
'Groups'[GroupLabel] = userInput
),
'Group'[GroupID]
)
```

However we also have an option that the user can select for "All" groups.  So in order to accomplish this, the table variable would need to look something like this:

```
DEFINE
VAR GroupIDs_Selected =
SUMMARIZE('Groups', 'Groups'[GroupID])
```

The above two variable definitions appear to work fine separately, but my problem is that I haven't figured out a way to combine these two variable definitions conditionally.  For example, the following definition which attempts to combine the above two definitions inside an IF function is not working for me:

```
DEFINE
VAR GroupIDs_Selected = 
IF( userInput = "All", 
SUMMARIZE('Groups', 'Groups'[GroupID]),
SUMMARIZE(
CALCULATETABLE(
'Groups', 
'Groups'[GroupLabel] = userInput
),
'Group'[GroupID]
)
```

^ More specifically, when I try to reference this conditional variable as a table (for example in an EVALUATE statement), I get the following error message:  "The expression specified in the query is not a valid table expression".

My question.. Is there something that I'm missing inside the IF statement?  Maybe I have to include a function to somehow cast the conditionally returned value as a table?  Or is this something that can't be done within a DAX table variable assignment statement?  Or is there another completely different way to handle this kind of scenario within a tabular model?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of parameter do you want to use. If it's simple one value text parameter then use a simple filter within SUMMARIZE like this

SSRS:

`par1 available values (A|B|C|D); users choice A`

DAX:

```
EVALUATE(
SUMMARIZECOLUMS(
'Item'[Category]
FILTER('Item', 'Item'[Group] = @ssrsParam)
"sales" [value of items]
)
```

If the parameter is multivalue you can do something like this

SSRS:

`par1 available values (A|B|C|D); users choice A and B`

in dataset use the par1 as a formula and concatenate value's using Join

```
=Join(Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value, "|")
```

DAX:

```
EVALUATE(
SUMMARIZECOLUMS(
'Item'[Category]
FILTER(VALUES('Item'[Group]), PATHCONTAINS(@ssrsParam, 'Item'[Group]))
"sales" [value of items]
)
```